# Can't do simple any JS with pjax enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I am working on a template that has pjax enabled: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax (http://demo.flatlogic.com/3.4.0/dark/stat_charts.html).

I have some Jquery code which I want to run on a button click. The button is inside the wrapper reloaded by pjax:

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on('click', 'a.btn', function() { ... });
});
```

The click event does work when I load the first page, however it fails to do so once I go to another page. I tried to listen to the pjax load event, however this didn't help. Anything else I need to know about this plugin?

Comment: the "onload" is the problem. name your ready callback, remove it from `$()`, and then add `$(theName)`. now, you can call `theName()` from anywhere to re-init the widget markup

Comment: @dandavis, may I ask you to provide a small example? Not sure if I've got everything.